# Test Azure Devops Services Organization

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migration

We are migrating from  Azure Devops Server on prem to Azure Devops Services. On prem we had two servers, the first for production and the second - the same - for test purposes. Since we had access to db, we were able to update test server whenever we want to production data using backup.

The question is: is it possible to manage somehow the same on Azure Devops Services? We want to have test organization that we will be able to update with new prod data later.

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about testing?

Comment: A lot of things, we need to be able to test, pipelines, wortkitems, global notifications, etc

Answer (score -1):

In the azure devops Service, We can create up to 5 different organizations. So you can try to migrate your test organization to the Azure Devops Service, and this will help you have the test organziation.